# Change insert copied text from Shift Ctrl V to Shift Insert

Tags: paste

In most cases, shift insert works when you want to insert copied text.

But in a terminal, it uses <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd>.

Any way to change that behaviour to <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Insert</kbd>?

Comment: In my terminal `Shift`+`Ins` returns `CA`+`Enter`+`5`+`Enter` which is pretty useless I think. I don't see any reason for keeping this configuration and allowing `Shift`+`Ins` to be remapped to paste from clipboard.

Comment: It isn't useless to me. It works in other apps.

Comment: @DK Bose You get the gold star. I use mate-terminal and it had a way to change keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your terminal may have a settings or preferences option. You maybe able to specify <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> there.

Lubuntu 18.04 has *lxterminal* as its default terminal. Click *Edit > Preferences > Shortcuts*. Then, click on the area next to *Paste* which should have the current keyboard shortcut for pasting, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Insert</kbd> simultaneously. The contents should change to reflect your choice. Press *OK*. That's all.

[image: lxterminal]

Similarly, *Konsole* (in Kubuntu 18.04) has <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> as an alternative to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> out of the box.

[image: konsole]

Comment: DK Bose provided a great answer.

I found that the middle mouse button also inserts text.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu Gnome go to the ribbon (3 horizontal lines) and open Preferences:

[image]